# Let $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, with $f(x)f(f(x)) = 1$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$. If $f(1000) = 999$, find $f(500)$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, with $f(x)f(f(x)) =
> 1$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$. If $f(1000) = 999$, find $f(500)$.

I try to solve this problem, but I don't know how to use de continuity on $f$. Is anyone could give me a little hint on the continuity? And please, don't give me the answer to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint 1: What can you say about $f(y)$ if $y$ is in the image of $f$?

Hint 2: The intermediate value theorem will be helpful. Note that $999$ is in the image of $f$.

Comment: I suspected that I could use the intermediate value theorem, but I do not know how. Thank you, I'll think now.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
Use Intermediate Value Theorem between $\frac{1}{999}$ and $999$.

$500$ belongs in this interval.