# Find $f(2015)$ if f is continuous and $f(2017)=2016$

Tags: functions

> If  $f:R\rightarrow R$ is a continuous function with the properties:
>   $f(2017)=2016$ and $f(x)\cdot f(f(x))=1$ find the value of $f(2015)$

I replaced $x$ with $2017$ and got $f(2017)\cdot f(f(2017))=1$

$2016\cdot f(2016)=1$ which means $f(2016)=\frac1{2016}$, but I don't know how to get to $f(2015)$

Comment: *Very* similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2227081/42969,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1464107/42969.

Comment: many thanks, you saved me

Answer (score 2):

You have that for every $y$ in the image of $f$ $f(y)=\frac 1y$. Furthermore 2016 and $\frac 1{2016}$ stay in the image, so since $f$ is continous also 2015 stays in the image. It follows that $f(2015)=\frac 1{2015}$

Comment: If $\displaystyle f(y)=\frac1y$, how can we have $f(2017)=2016\not=\frac1{2017}$?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva it means that 2017 doesn’t stay in the range of $f$!

Answer (score 0):

$f(t)=\frac 1 t$ for any $t$ in the range of $f$. Since $\frac  1 {2016}$ and $2016$ are both in the range and $f$ is continuous it any number between these two is in the range. So $f(2015)=\frac 1  {2015}$.